# MongoEngine search index

Tags: mongodb, search, mongoengine, inverted-index

I'm trying to implement an inverted-index search engine with MongoDb (MongoEngine) where terms in Posts are assigned weights and then used as embedded documents like such:

```
class Term(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    t = db.StringField()
    weight = db.FloatField()

class Post(db.Document):
    terms = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Term))
```

Then given a term, I can find the Posts that contain the term using this query:

```
post_list = Post.objects(terms__t=term)
```

However, this returns a list of Posts, but how can I find the weight of the term for each returned Post without having to iterate through the list of embedded terms looking for the term? Is there a way to query the Posts to automatically return the weight for any returned Posts as well?

Also would appreciate if anyone has any better methods of implementing a search engine in MongoDB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports a basic text index see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/ This is a better way to store and search against documents, especially if you want a score for the match.

You'd have to call the command manually as its not currently implemented in MongoEngine.